# DATE_ADD add month and day interval

Tags: php, mysql

So PHP does not accept doing something along the lines of:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_ADD('" . $this->db->escape($data['regpro_buy_date']) . "', INTERVAL " . $year_flag . " YEAR + INTERVAL " . $mon_flag . " MONTH) AS warranty_date; ";
```

but if I do:

```
SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 2 YEAR + INTERVAL 2 MONTH
```

in MYSql it works fine. I am unsure of how to get it to where month and year are working together.

currently month and year are defined as:

```
$year_flag = 2;
$mon_flag = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, nevermind, I was able to figure it out.

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD('" . $this->db->escape($data['regpro_buy_date']) . "', INTERVAL " . $year_flag . " YEAR), INTERVAL " . $mon_flag . " MONTH) AS warranty_date; ";
```